# How to manipulate WPF GUI based on user roles

Tags: c#, wpf, security, xaml, identity

I am using .NET's IIdentity and IPrincipal objects for role based security, and I am at the step of modifying controls shown based on roles the current user has.

My question is what the recommended method is for enabling/disabling fields in a WPF window - showing/hiding fields dependent on IIdentity.IsInRole type calls.

Can this be done in XAML, or do I have to abstract this into code with what I think is a bit messy in the code behind;

```
this.txtUserName.IsReadOnly = !MyPrincipal.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("Administrator");
this.mnuCreateUser.Visibility = MyPrincipal.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("Administrator");
 ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
```

(Note; my code checks roles when executing functions, what I am looking to do is modifying the GUI dependent on the roles, so users do not see/see readonly elements that they do not have access to)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although previous answer will work, to me it looks little ugly to detect visibility in logic objects. I would use converter for that...

```
<Control Visibility={Binding Path=CurrentPrincipal, Converter={StaticResource RoleToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Administrator}/>
```

And then the converter itself

```
public class RoleToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var principal = value as Principal;
        if(principal != null) {
            return principal.IsInRole((string)parameter) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, this is very much to my liking. With this in the XAML it should be straight forward to see the access that is required to see the different elements in the GUI. Thank you.

Comment: fellow code swipers, you may need to add "return" before "new NotImplementedException();"

Comment: I'd probably return either Visibility.Visible at the end or Visibility.Collapsed instead of null depending on whether you want an anonymous user to be able to view the item. (I chose Visibility.Collapsed).

Comment: I edited the line: var principal = value as Principal; to read: var principal = value as IPrincipal; Also be aware that you will require a reference to System.Security and a "using System.Security.Principal;" statement

Comment: What if multiple Roles have same Visibility settings for a specific control? How could you send multiple ConverterParameters E.g. `ConverterParameter=Admin,Developer`?

Comment: Few years old now but Adolfo Perez I changed the code to have   
string[] roles = ((string)parameter).Split('|');
return roles.Any(role => principal.IsInRole(role)) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

Answer (score 1):

```
<Control Visibility={Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=AdministratorVisibility, Mode=OneWay}/>
```

In your C# code:

```
public Visibility AdministratorVisibility
{
    get 
    { 
        MyPrincipal.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("Administrator") ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible; 
    }
}
```

You can do the same thing for implementing something for `IsReadOnly`. If the user's role can change (I'm not sure how these user roles work), you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and do `NotifyPropertyChanged("AdministratorVisibility")`, otherwise you could probably change the `BindingMode` to `BindingMode.OneTime` and skip implementing the notifications.

This probably isn't a whole lot better than what you're doing already, but it's probably as good as you're going to get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The roles I am using update only when closing and re-opening the application, so NotifyPropertyChange is not critical. I thought about this method, but was hoping that something more direct existed - sorta like the role attribute syntax one can use on methods.