# WPF GUI Manage using Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: wpf, security, binding

Hi I found this questions

[How to manipulate WPF GUI based on user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019204/how-to-manipulate-wpf-gui-based-on-user-roles/1020303#1020303)

and apply his answer to my project. I'm implementing the same behavior.

but the thing is the property binding doesn't work.

I create the RoleToVisibilityConverter class and make some test, calling the convert

```
RoleToVisibilityConverter conv = new RoleToVisibilityConverter();  
conv.Convert((object)Thread.CurrentPrincipal,cbo_organismo.GetType(),(object)"editor",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

this work find, then i add the resources to my usercontrol

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<fundafe:RoleToVisibilityConverter x:Key="roleConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and make the binding to my button control

```
<Button Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding Source=Thread.CurrentPrincipal,  Path=CurrentPrincipal, Converter={StaticResource roleConverter}, ConverterParameter=editor}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="btn_Eliminar" Click="btn_Eliminar_Click" Width="Auto" Height="25" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                         <Image Name="img_eliminar" Width="48" Source="imagenes/borrar.png" Height="19" />
                    </Button>
```

after running  my application, the button is still visible.

if i'm hardcoding the Visibility property the button is hidden

```
btn_Eliminar.Visibility=(Visibility)conv.Convert((object)Thread.CurrentPrincipal,cbo_organismo.GetType(),(object)"editor",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Any suggestion?

**Note:**
I'cant use the last approach because in my real scenario the button is part of a DataTemplate for a ListView, and even if a capture the button using the TreeHelper the ListView only apply the change to the first items due to virtualization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your code verbatim, it looks like the Binding on your `Button` is wrong. You have this:

```
{Binding Source=Thread.CurrentPrincipal,  Path=CurrentPrincipal, Converter={StaticResource roleConverter}, ConverterParameter=editor}
```

Notice that you've bound to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` as your source, but then you set the `Path` to `CurrentPrincipal` as well. This equates to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.CurrentPrincipal` which would obviously fail to bind.

Honestly I'm pretty sure you need an `{x:Static}` around the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` as well. Plus that means you need a namespace for `System.Threading` declared. Assuming you define the namespace as "systhreading" so the final binding would be:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static systhreading:Thread.CurrentPrincipal},  Converter={StaticResource roleConverter}, ConverterParameter=editor}
```

Comment: Hi I'm new with wpf so I don't get all this binding thing, thanks for the help.
I add this references xmlns:systhreading="clr-namespace:System.Threading;assembly=System" 
but I get a error: the type Thread is not find, any idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The Thread class is actually in the mscorlib assembly. So your namespace declaration should be: xmlns:systhreading="clr-namespace:System.Threading;assembly=mscorlib".