# Show/hide controls based on user role in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need to do a quick sample WPF application where the controls on the forms should be made visible or hidden based on the user roles.

Something like this will be great,
[How to manipulate WPF GUI based on user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019204/how-to-manipulate-wpf-gui-based-on-user-roles/1020303#1020303)

I am not sure where to put the XAML defined in the thread(`<Control` ) so that the every control in the form uses RoleToVisibilityConverter to show or hide the controls.

i am very new to windows dev..could you please help me ?

Regards
Bala

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by binding the Visibility to a corresponding property in your code-behind/ViewModel.

This is an example from a binding in one of my testcontrols using WPF (in combination with Caliburn):

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsAdmin}"
```

Here I have a bool property in my ViewModel called IsAdmin.

Comment: `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` ;)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easiest way was creating a global variable in my app. For that, go to your `Project->Properties->Settings.settings` and create a new variable (called, for example, Administrator), and set it to `True` of `False` depending on what you want to do. Something like this:

[image]

Then, at your `MainWindow`, when its initialized, you can write this:

```
if (!Properties.Settings.Default.Administrator)
{
    DisableSettings();
}
```

And then, disable the fields you want to.